# Expression Language 3.0 is Parsing my Conditionals as Lambdas

Tags: java, jsp, parsing, lambda, el

So I've just updated our JSP from 2.2 to 2.3, and hence Expression Language too has been updated to 3.0

Now the problem is, any statement that goes :

${(x) != (y)} (example conditional)

Throws the error :

Error : Encountered '!=', Expected '->'

I fixed the error in a few files, but my software has thousands of lines worth of code where I use a statement like the one above.

Is there a way for the parser to NOT consider these as lambda expressions?